How to Configure HSL MA86 for Use w/ IPOPT in OpenMDAO
I am currently trying to configure the HSL MA86 linear solver for use with IPOPT in OpenMDAO. I am using a Linux Ubuntu computer. I have extracted both HSL MA86 and IPOPT from tar.gz files and created the folders in their necessary locations. I have installed BLAS, LAPACK, and METIS, all of which are dependencies for HSL MA86. I have also configured MA86 to be linked to the dependencies and their paths.
When I try to run my code using OpenMDAO, I encounter the following printout from IPOPT:
   Exit Status
      Inform  Description
         -12  Invalid Option
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

This only occurs when I have the following line uncommented:
p.driver.opt_settings['linear_solver'] = 'ma86'

I am uncertain of why this is happening. It seems that IPOPT is not connected to HSL MA86.
It is worth mentioning that each time I attempt to run make install  (after running make and make check) for HSL MA86, I encounter the following error printout snippit (actual filepaths have been redacted for privacy):
/usr/bin/install: 'include/hsl_ma86s.h' and '/path/to/hsl_ma86-1.7.4/include/hsl_ma86s.h' are the same file
/usr/bin/install: 'include/hsl_ma86d.h' and '/path/to/hsl_ma86-1.7.4/include/hsl_ma86d.h' are the same file
/usr/bin/install: 'include/hsl_ma86c.h' and '/path/to/hsl_ma86-1.7.4/include/hsl_ma86c.h' are the same file
/usr/bin/install: 'include/hsl_ma86z.h' and '/path/to/hsl_ma86-1.7.4/include/hsl_ma86z.h' are the same file
/usr/bin/install: 'include/hsl_mc68i.h' and '/path/to/hsl_ma86-1.7.4/include/hsl_mc68i.h' are the same file
/usr/bin/install: 'include/hsl_mc69s.h' and '/path/to/hsl_ma86-1.7.4/include/hsl_mc69s.h' are the same file
/usr/bin/install: 'include/hsl_mc69d.h' and '/path/to/hsl_ma86-1.7.4/include/hsl_mc69d.h' are the same file
/usr/bin/install: 'include/hsl_mc69c.h' and '/path/to/hsl_ma86-1.7.4/include/hsl_mc69c.h' are the same file
/usr/bin/install: 'include/hsl_mc69z.h' and '/path/to/hsl_ma86-1.7.4/include/hsl_mc69z.h' are the same file
make[2]: *** [Makefile:418: install-includeHEADERS] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/path/to/hsl_ma86-1.7.4'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:749: install-am] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/path/to/hsl_ma86-1.7.4'
make: *** [Makefile:445: install-recursive] Error 1

I am wondering if this is potentially the issue? Another potential source of error could be the path not fully connecting? By default, my variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not set to path/to/hsl_ma86-1.7.4/lib. I use the following code structure to change it between what it originally is and to the needed path for my OpenMDAO program:
import os
import subprocess

def my_function():
    # Path to HSL MA86 libraries -- needed to temporarily change for OpenMDAO code
    ma86_path = "/path/to/hsl_ma86-1.7.4/lib"

    # Obtains the original library path necessary for other code
    original_libPath = os.environ.get('LD_LIBRARY_PATH', '')    

    try:
        # Temporarily sets the library path to HSL MA86 so that IPOPT can find it
        # os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = f"{ma86_path}:{original_libPath}"
        os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = ma86_path
        print('LD_LIBRARY_PATH: {}'.format(os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH']))
        print('Subprocess executed')
        # Execute trajectory code using HSL MA86
        subprocess.run(["python", "my_openmdao_code.py"])
        

    finally:
        # Resets initial library path for use in optimization
        os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = original_libPath
        print('Restoration Occured')
        print('LD_LIBRARY_PATH: {}'.format(os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH']))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    my_function()

Sorry that this is such a long post, but I wanted to provide as much detail as I could. Thanks for the help!

If running Ipopt with linear_solver=ma86 gives an invalid option response, then maybe Ipopt has been build without HSL_MA86 and without the possibility to load the MA86 routines at runtime (https://coin-or.github.io/Ipopt/INSTALL.html#DOWNLOAD_HSL).
For use with Ipopt, there is a special HSL source package available (https://licences.stfc.ac.uk/product/coin-hsl). There are also prebuild libraries (https://licences.stfc.ac.uk/products/Software/HSL/libhsl).
